# How to restart timer?

Tags: c#

I have this Code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
    {
        left = true;
        right = false;
        down = false;
    }
}

private void timerMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Ghost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel3.Bounds))
    {
        timerMoving.Stop();
    }

    if(left)
    {
        Ghost.Left -= 5;
        timerMoving.Start();
    }
}
```

In the above code as my Ghost(which is moving down) hits the panel3 boundary it stops.
I want my timer to start again as i press Left,Right or up key and only stop when it's moving down,hitting panel3. I tried doing this:

```
if(left)
{
    Ghost.Left -= 5;
    timerMoving.Start();
}
```

but nothing happens, Why?

Comment: You can't start the timer in the tick event.

Comment: Because that code is inside your timer Tick event and you stopped it, so it will never execute again...

Comment: Then where am i supposed to do it? i want to restart the timer again.

Comment: @LarsTech I understand what you say, but it leads to think you can't reenable a timer inside it's Tick event, and indeed you can, suppose you stop it on the tick but your logic requires to reenable it, then it's perfectly valid to reenable insde the Tick event.

Comment: Hook to the KeyPress/KeyDown/KeyUp event

Comment: You want to start the timer when the left key is pressed. You have an event handler that fires when a key is pressed.

Comment: There's no enough context. You can restart the timer inside the tick event of a timer that isn't running. So you need to do it outside. In the keydown event you could check if the timer is running and, if not, start if there.

Comment: You are thinking one-dimensionally, like procedural programming. You are using OOP and event-based programming to make your game, therefore, an event occurs, you capture the event, then do your stuff. That's how event-based programming works. You hook into events and "do stuff".

Comment: @Gusman I was just cutting to the chase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple (though not the optimal) way to achieve this goal pertinent to your task description is by adding the line shown in the following code snippet:

```
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
        {
         // add this line   
            if(!timerMoving.Enabled) timerMoving.Start();        
            left = true;
            right = false;
            down = false;
            up = false;

        }
     }
```

and removing this line as shown below:

```
 if (left)
        {

            Ghost.Left -= 5;
            //timerMoving.Start(); - comment off
        }
```

Hope this may help.